# Telnet to windows host backspace key wrong

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, telnet

When telneting to a windows host from a linux guest, attempts to use the backspace key leads to odd characters being output - and nothing being deleted.

Is there something to get the windows telnet service to behave "normally" for this key press?

I am using the /usr/bin/telnet client - from an FC17 machine, from a bash session in GNOME Terminal 3.4.1.1. The $TERM variable is xterm.

If I telnet from another windows machine to the server, I don't see the same behaviour - so there must be some setting in the client.

Comment: sounds like a rubbish client!

Comment: Unhelpful. This isn't some exotic weird client. This is one that is standard.

Comment: well windows has a rubbish telnet client so many people use putty. If an OS has a rubbish telnet client it's not unhelpful to know it and then use a recommended alternative.  I'm not a big linux user but what you describe sounds like what i've seen from a bad telnet client and would make me look at using a different telnet client. A popular one.

Comment: Hmm - there is a putty build for linux. I'll try that and see if it works for this...

Comment: Hmm - no better - are there recommended settings for a windows host in putty?

Comment: putty is just a client, but there are "ssh servers" that should do telnet too http://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows

Comment: I meant terminal settings for the putty client to get normal behaviour from the default windows telnet server (normal meaning that backspace, cursor keys etc work by moving cursors and deleting characters visibly, and not deleting the prompt).

Comment: well, tested from windows xp to windows xp with putty client to windows xp's tlntsvr.exe works fine and looks like this http://i.imgur.com/XWOySWA.png   backspace works. Try looking in Putty under "Terminal..Keyboard..The backspace key"" Mine is on Control-?(127).  Not on control-H  Under "the funtion keys and keypad" mine is set to ESC[n~. The only time I might've seen what you describe is back when I used to use windows's native telnet.exe client (a rubbish client) and then I recall not being able to use arrow keys and maybe not be able to use backsapce.